# How many points are needed to earn medals in Flappy Bird?

Tags: flappy-bird

I've scored 7 points so far in Flappy Bird.

How many points are required to earn the different medals?

Comment: Oh god, first and probably last question about flappy bird on Arqade, hourra! :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Medals are awarded at the following points:

- **Bronze**: 10 pts
- **Silver**: 20 pts
- **Gold**: 30 pts
- **Platinum**: 40 pts

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I scored 54 points and still got a silver medal, and my friend scored 139 points and also still got a silver medal.

Comment: maybe u mix up silver with platinum