# How many points are required to earn medals?

Tags: swing-copters

I have not gotten a high enough score to recieve a medal in Swing Copters.

How many points do I need to earn medals?

Comment: Oh damn you for mentioning this game! Now I have a reason to throw around my phone again ;P

Comment: Darn I was just about to ask this question too xD

Answer (score 3):

The medals as of version 1.1.0 (before that they were only half of that) are:

```
+----------+----+
| Bronze   | 20 |
| Silver   | 30 |
| Gold     | 60 |
| Platinum | 80 |
+----------+----+
```

I reached all of them myself but earlier versions of this answer were based on another post ([How many points are needed to earn medals in Flappy Bird?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/155658)).

A difference between flappy bird and swing copters is that you also unlock new outfits with new medals.

Comment: I have gotten ten points and I still don't have a medal...

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't update my post yet for version 1.1.0 but I think giving a downvote is not appropriate especially because there is another answer which states the same.

Answer (score 1):

The medals were adjusted with the recent update- made the game easier, spread the medals out accordingly. 20 is the new bronze, and 30 doesn't get you anything new, so I'm guessing 20-40-60-80.

Answer (score 0):

I got a medal at 10 points. Good luck!

Comment: What kind of medal? Are there any other medals?

Comment: Maybe you should adjust your answer: the newest update has proven this wrong